# Round number when inserting in database

Tags: mysql

I want to round the entry in sql  INSERT.
For example if i have  the price : 5.345654 - it must take 5.34 and insert it.

Here is my code: but it doesn't work.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (price) VALUES '(round($price, 2))')";
```

Comment: INSERT INTO users (price) VALUES (round($price, 2)) ;

Comment: The job of the database is to record data, not to mangle it. The real question here is why do you have 5.345645 in the first place? Using floating-point for money perhaps? Don't do that. Use BigDecimal, and control the precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, it should work

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (price) VALUES (round($price, 2))";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing `)` round brace and u should be good to go